# Parse error: unexpected ')' in TwitterOAuth.php on line 58 - Need help resolving syntax error

Tags: php, parsing, twitter, syntax-error

I'm encountering a syntax error in the TwitterOAuth library for PHP. The error message I'm getting is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting variable
> (T_VARIABLE) in TwitterOAuth.php on line 58

Here's what you need to know:

```
Error Type: Syntax error, indicating an issue with the code's structure or grammar.

Affected File: TwitterOAuth.php.
Line Number: Line 58.

Context or Relevant Code Snippet:
[Include the code snippet around line 58 in TwitterOAuth.php].
```

I've already checked my code for any obvious syntax errors, and I've searched online for solutions, but I couldn't find any specific ones.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this syntax error and successfully use the TwitterOAuth library.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Not enough info. What is the code at line 58? ... and before that point as well? ... Line 58 is the PHP parser's `best guess` as to where it believes the problem to be, but the real issue can be somewhere before that point as well (like in another file before that point, as an example), if there's nothing obvious at line 58.

Comment: Possible duplicate? [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem? I'm facing the same

Answer (score 0):

This is line 52-58 of that library:

[source](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/blob/main/src/TwitterOAuth.php#L58)

```php
    public function __construct(
        string $consumerKey,
        string $consumerSecret,
        ?string $oauthToken = null,
        ?string $oauthTokenSecret = null,
    ) {
```

My *guess* is that the trailing comma is a feature that was added to a PHP version more recent than the one you're using.

The library requires PHP 8 it seems.